# Postfix/Dovecot import mail from Gmail

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I setup an iRedMail server on Ubuntu 14.04. My company currently uses Gmail but wants to switch to a cheaper solution. I set up the server with an LDAP DB, and I'm using Postfix and Dovecot for the server and transfer agent.

Is there a way to import or POP email from Gmail into iRedMail?

Comment: How many email boxes do you have to migrate?

Comment: 150 give or take a few

Comment: That is probably a bit too much users for the solution I had in mind, but you can try with `offlineimap`, which is a script that copies email between different IMAP servers, local directories and other. It may be somewhat handmade for your needs, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: Okay, Ill take a look at that, It might work. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try `imapsync` at https://imapsync.lamiral.info/ (Also available in AUR). It can migrate email between any two imap servers easily. It officially supports most email servers, and most OS. (including iRedMail, Gmail and Ubuntu)

Basic usage: `imapsync --host1 imap.host1.com --user1 user@example.com --password1 P@ssw0rd --host2 imap.host2.com --user2 user@example.com --password2 P@ssw0rd`.

Comment: Given that the OP indicates they're using Ubuntu (albeit, 3 years ago now), it might be more pertinent & useful to indicate the corresponding installation steps for Ubuntu.

Comment: @JeffSchaller There're complete installation guides for every OS and an online-imapsync tool in the provided official website. I think that's easy enough to use:)

Comment: Please note this is a commercial product. I spotted that it is free only for 3gb or less.